# Set State not working with bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a very simple setState work with the bottomnavigationbar, but I'm having some problems.
Can anyone help me?

```
@override
void initState() {
utente = widget.utente;
_tabs = [paginadatiUtente(), paginadatiUtente(), paginadatiUtente()];

super.initState();
```

}

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Image.asset('lib/assets/titolo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),        
  ),
  body: _tabs[navigationIndex],
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: navigationIndex,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: const [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: "Home",
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: "Filtri",
        icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: "Utente",
        icon: Icon(Icons.manage_accounts),
      ),
    ],
    onTap: (value) => setState(() {
      navigationIndex = value;
    }),
  ),
);

Widget paginadatiUtente() {
return Column(
    children: [
      Text(stringa),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              stringa = "Cambiato";
            });
          },
          child: const Text("cambia"))
    ],
);
```

}

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible.
Pressing the page button does not change the text.

Comment: Show the code where `stringa` is first declared.

Comment: First: _tabs has 3 times the same content. Second: Where is navigationbarIndex defined? Make sure it's not set to default on build

Comment: @Steffomio there are many lines I tried to simplify as much as possible

above all
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String stringa = "prima";
  int navigationIndex = 1;

Answer (score 0):

you might not be able to arrow function into a set state like that, that is the only difference i am seeing from the sample on the flutter docs

```
onTap: (value) {
   print("tapped ${value}"); // for debugging
   setState(() {
    navigationIndex = value;
   });
},
```

Comment: ontap is called regularly, but it doesn't update the page body

Comment: ok, there is also a new version of BottomNavigationBar, called NavigationBar, which i personally find much easier to implement. i can update my answer with some sample code if needed.